# SSIS File System task didn't copy files from the source server location when scheduled

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I'm new to SSIS and stuck with a problem and hope some of them would have already gone through any of this.

Task:
Copying files from a remote server to a local machine folder using File System task and For each loop container.

Problem:
The job executes i.e. files are getting copied successfully when I execute from the SSIS designer but when deployed the project on the SQL server instance it isn't copying any files in fact the target folder is totally empty.

I'm not understanding this strange behavior. Any inputs would be of great help!

Regards-
Santosh G.

Comment: Are you using any parameters in your SSIS project?

Comment: Any error? Log file? Anything?

Comment: I'm not using any parameters and even error log is not generated. The job gets successfully executed in SSMS Agent

Answer (score 0):

The For each loop will not error out if it doesn't find any files.

The SQL Agent account may not have access to read the directory contents.

Check is your path a variable - is it being set by a config or /SET statement?
Can you log the path before starting the for loop?

Can you copy a dummy file and see can SSIS see this file?

How are you running the job - cmd_exec() can give spurious results with file I/O tasks

Comment: In the for each loop container I directly selected the path of the server.
I haven't assigned any specific path variable and I can logon to the path before starting the loop.
However, these things are perfectly working fine in the SSIS designer.
My SSIS Analysis service is working under the Local systemaccount and the SSMS Agent service is also working under the Local system account.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the user authorizarions of the SQL Server agent service.

When I execute the job from SQL Server it uses agent service and for that agent service you need to assign a service user who has access rights to the desired file path.